# change the layout of views in a recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have 2 different layouts which I want to use for my views in specific situations in a `Recycler View`. the user decides which layout should appear. how is it possible to change the layout of my views which are being shown in the recycler view at run time? I think I need to force my adapter to restart and recreate and rearrange the views. how to do that at a way that I don't lose my `insert` animation?

UPDATE:

```
public class InfinityFragmentRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter implements HasDatabase
{
  protected JsonDatabase jsonDatabase = new JsonDatabase(null);
protected Context mContext;
protected int arrangeMode;

public InfinityFragmentRecyclerAdapter(Context context, int viewMode)
{
    mContext = context;
    arrangeMode = viewMode;
}

// this is the method which enables me to change the view mode
public void setNewArrangeMode(int mode)
{
    arrangeMode = mode;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
{
    View view;
    if (arrangeMode == SupportsGridAndListArrangement.GRID_VIEW)
    {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate
                (R.layout.grid_layout, null);
    }
    else
    {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate
                (R.layout.list_layout, null);
    }
    return new ItemHolder(view, mContext, arrangeMode);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i)
{
....
    if (arrangeMode == SupportsGridAndListArrangement.LIST_VIEW)
    {
        ...

        StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                new StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams
                        (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
        viewHolder.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    if (jsonDatabase != null)
    {
        return jsonDatabase.getCount();
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public Object getDatabase()
{
    return jsonDatabase;
}


public void append(Object newJsonDatabase)
{
    int currentCount = 0;
    if (jsonDatabase != null)
    {
        currentCount = jsonDatabase.getCount();
    }
    int newCount = ((JsonDatabase) newJsonDatabase).getCount();
    jsonDatabase.appendAtEnd((JsonDatabase) newJsonDatabase);
    for (int i = currentCount; i < (currentCount + newCount); i++)
    {
        notifyItemInserted(i);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: When calling `inflater.inflate(R.layout.blahblah, parent, false);` you can wrap it in an if statement and inflate the appropriate layout. You won't lose any animation? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: At runtime ? like after the listitems are already visible ? what happens when you use notifydatasetchanged after your boolean or whatever you use to determine which layout should be shown is set in the item ?

Comment: @ScriptKitty what u say is correct for the first time. but the problem is that `onCreateViewHolder` has already been called

Comment: @ChristianStengel yes, exactly. I don't know why but when i call  notifydatasetchanged , `onCreateViewHolder` does not get called so the new views can not get generated

Comment: Can you post your onCreateViewHolder as well as your whole adapter please? I want to see if it is possible to make that method generoc

Comment: @ScriptKitty I updated my post

Comment: Design wise, I think you may look into creating 2 recycleradapters. Not sure yet